# How to convert symmetric matrix to adjacency table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

How could I convert symmetric matrix:

```
  A B C D
A 1 2 3 4
B 2 1 2 3
C 3 2 1 2
D 4 3 2 1
```

into adjacency matrix?:

```
A A 1
A B 2
A C 3 
A D 4
B A 3
B B 1
B C 2
B D 3
C A 3
C C 1
C D 2
D A 4
D B 3
D C 2
D D 1
```

Is there any function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a pandas dataframe as input, you can use numpy to get the [`triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, index=list('ABCD'), columns=list('ABCD'))

#    A  B  C  D
# A  1  2  3  4
# B  2  1  2  3
# C  3  2  1  2
# D  4  3  2  1

a = df.to_numpy()
x,y = np.triu_indices(len(df))

out = pd.DataFrame({'x': df.index[x], 'y':  df.columns[y], 'value': a[x,y]})
```

output:

```
   x  y  value
0  A  A      1
1  A  B      2
2  A  C      3
3  A  D      4
4  B  B      1
5  B  C      2
6  B  D      3
7  C  C      1
8  C  D      2
9  D  D      1
```

###### all combinations

```
df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='column')
```

output:

```
   index column  value
0      A      A      1
1      B      A      2
2      C      A      3
3      D      A      4
4      A      B      2
5      B      B      1
6      C      B      2
7      D      B      3
8      A      C      3
9      B      C      2
10     C      C      1
11     D      C      2
12     A      D      4
13     B      D      3
14     C      D      2
15     D      D      1
```

or, for a different order:

```
df.stack().rename_axis(['index', 'columns']).reset_index(name='value')
```

output:

```
   index columns  value
0      A       A      1
1      A       B      2
2      A       C      3
3      A       D      4
4      B       A      2
5      B       B      1
6      B       C      2
7      B       D      3
8      C       A      3
9      C       B      2
10     C       C      1
11     C       D      2
12     D       A      4
13     D       B      3
14     D       C      2
15     D       D      1
```

Comment: thx, but it doesn't prevent you from getting A B and B A for example

Comment: @gh1222 yes it does, it only takes the above-diagonal (upper triangle) elements. See the output for yourself

Comment: well, it does in my example

Comment: Can you elaborate? Here the reshaping is purely dune by position (not names). Provide a counter example if needed.

Comment: yeah you right, i wrote my question wrong. i need to get all possible pairs, so there must be 16 rows

Comment: @gh1222 then you need a simple `df.reset_index().melt('index')` or `df.stack()`:p

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `pandas.stack()` and reset the index values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, index=list('ABCD'), columns=list('ABCD'))

#    A  B  C  D
# A  1  2  3  4
# B  2  1  2  3
# C  3  2  1  2
# D  4  3  2  1

df = df.stack().reset_index()
df['ordered-name'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted([x['level_0'],x['level_1']])),axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ordered-name'])
df.drop(['ordered-name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
#    level_0  level_1  0
# 0        A        A  1
# 1        A        B  2
# 2        A        C  3
# 3        A        D  4
# 4        B        B  1
# 5        B        C  2
# 6        B        D  3
# 7        C        C  1
# 8        C        D  2
# 9        D        D  1
```

You can change the names of the columns as you wish.

Comment: This is not the correct output of `stack`, `stack` should give all pairs (A,B) and (B,A) so 16 rows here, not 10

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, it can be changed by deleting 'duplicates', but your solution is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

It actually already is an adjacency matrix (as you would use it for a directed graph).
I guess what you're looking for an Adjacency List or considering your example an Adjacency Map (for an undirected graph).
I'm not sure if there is a built-in function for such a conversion (assuming you're using pandas dataframes considering the used tags).
The easiest way of doing it is just reading the top (or just the bottom) triangle of the matrix which shouldn't take up too many iterations in a loop and just constructing it that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).